# 2 map function loops returns an undefined array instead of a jsx table row element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, jsx

I have this code which uses the map function to go through an object

the object schema is this one:
**result_petrol_data.result**

```
{
    "id": 51019,
    "name": "BEYFIN",
    "fuels": [
        {
            "id": 43917493,
            "price": 1.669,
            "name": "Benzina",
            "fuelId": 1,
            "isSelf": false
        },
        {
            "id": 43917492,
            "price": 1.639,
            "name": "Benzina",
            "fuelId": 1,
            "isSelf": true
        }
    ],
    "location": {
        "lat": 00.1234567890,
        "lng": 5.1234567890
    },
    "insertDate": "2022-10-10T07:47:59+02:00",
    "address": "Via Roma something",
    "brand": "Beyfin"
}
```

`maxResult` is the max length that I want for the result list

**first** map goes through *all the results*

**second** one goes through *all the petrol pumps for that specific fuel distributor*

```
let finalList = result_petrol_data.results.slice(0, maxResult).map((row, index) => {

                row.fuels.map((fuel) => {


                    //Check if the pump is the selected fuel preference
                    if (fuel.name == fuel_type_selected) { 
                        fuel_price = fuel.price.toString().replace('.', ',');

                        //Checks that the pump has the preferred dispensing method selected by the user
                        if (fuel.isSelf == is_fuelpump_selfservice) { 
                            
                            return (<tr key={index} ><td>{row.name}</td> </tr>)
                        }
                        else if (is_fuelpump_selfservice === undefined) {
                           return (//tr with some style changes)

                        }
                    }
                })
            })
```

finally when I print the `finalList` inside a table like this with `maxResult` set to 5:

```
<Table striped hover responsive size="sm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Nome</th>
            <th scope="col">Prezzo</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
     </thead >
     <tbody>
         {listItems}
     </tbody>

</Table>
```

I should see 5 table rows with the name value, like this:

```
<tr key=0 ><td>Name 1</td> </tr>
...
<tr key=4 ><td>Name 5</td> </tr>
```

Instead I get 5 undefined values like this (obviously are not displayed):

```
[
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
]
```

Comment: So what if neither of your `if`s match? Then you return nothing, i.e. `undefined`. (Also, `null` is not the same as `undefined`.)

Comment: You return nothing from the first `map` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to filter the results that have the type of petrol you want

```
const validResults = result_petrol_data
  .results
  .filter(result => result
    .fuels
    .some(fuel => fuel.name === fuel_type_selected)
  );
```

then you can slice them to get the N results you want

```
const validNResults = validResults.slice(0, maxResult);
```

and now you can map over them to create the elements you want. (*which you need to `return`*)

```
const finalList = validNResults
    .map((row, index) => {
      const fuelToUse = result
        .fuels
        .find(fuel => 
          fuel.name === fuel_type_selected && 
          (fuelToUse.isSelf === is_fuelpump_selfservice || is_fuelpump_selfservice === undefined)
        );

      if (fuelToUse.isSelf === is_fuelpump_selfservice) {
        return (<tr key={index}><td>{row.name}</td></tr>);
      } else if (is_fuelpump_selfservice === undefined) {
        // return tr with some style changes
        return (<tr key={index}><td>{row.name}</td></tr>);
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return inside both map loop.

```
let finalList = result_petrol_data.results.slice(0, maxResult).map((row, index) => {

            **return** row.fuels.map((fuel) => {


                //Check if the pump is the selected fuel preference
                if (fuel.name == fuel_type_selected) { 
                    fuel_price = fuel.price.toString().replace('.', ',');

                    //Checks that the pump has the preferred dispensing method selected by the user
                    if (fuel.isSelf == is_fuelpump_selfservice) { 
                        
                        return (<tr key={index} ><td>{row.name}</td> </tr>)
                    }
                    else if (is_fuelpump_selfservice === undefined) {
                       return (//tr with some style changes)

                    }
                }
            })
        })
```